# SCALA PLAY 2.3 Redis Cluster Execution exception[[JedisMovedDataException: MOVED play 2.3

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, redis-cluster

I am having a Redis cluster and want to use it as the Play 2.3 Cache.
Every time the app tries to write to the cluster I get the following error.

> Execution exception[[JedisMovedDataException: MOVED

Is there a way to tell the plugin that this is the cluster?

```
"com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.3.1"
```

Comment: I have used this custom plugin with a Redis cluster successfully so it might be something you could explore - https://github.com/KarelCemus/play-redis/blob/2.5.0/doc/20-configuration.md#standalone-vs-cluster

Comment: I have tried it and it fails on the brado connector for 2.11 saying the dependency is not found, Also there is not documentation for the cluster settings for 2.3

Answer (score 0):

May be you might be connected to the cluster mode of redis.
If Jedis doesn't support it then switched to lettuce which is very similar to jedis with advanced capabilities.